# Why is my EA not moving my position to breakeven?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, mt4

I'm attempting to modify my market orders to breakeven the position when the position get 100 pips to the good. This also accounts for the `StopLevels` which are around 20-30 pips for my broker. It checks the param's via a "`for(){...}` loop" function

The `MagicNumber` is the timeframe number for the chart it is on (i.e. **`240`**=4H, **`60`**=1H) I don't set a `TakeProfit` price & **initially no `StopLoss` price.**

The <kbd>EA</kbd> is not adding a `SL` to be equal to the opening price when the trade reaches 100 pip in profit (plus stoplevels). Profit points reaches well over 130 points.

My code is below for a **`OP_SELL`** order - any help would be appreciated. Regards, Todd

```
/*Global Declarations*/
double   pnlPoints;
double   price, sl, tp;
double   point;
int      stopLevel;
int      breakeven;
double   newSL; 

/*Local  Declaratons*/
pnlPoints            =  0;
point                =       MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_POINT );
stopLevel            =  int( MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL )
                           + MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_SPREAD )
                             );
sl                   =  NormalizeDouble( OrderStopLoss(), Digits );
tp                   =  OrderTakeProfit();
breakeven            =  100;


   for( int s = OrdersTotal() - 1; s >= 0; s-- )
   {    if ( (  OrderSelect( s, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES ) ) == true )
                price = MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_ASK );

        newSL     =  NormalizeDouble( OrderOpenPrice(), Digits );
        pnlPoints = ( OrderOpenPrice() - price ) / point;

        if (                          OP_SELL   == OrderType()               )
              if (                    Period()  == OrderMagicNumber()        )
                    if (              stopLevel <  ( newSL - price ) / point )
                          if (        breakeven <  pnlPoints                 )
                                if (  newSL     != sl                        )

                                      ModSell = OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                                             OrderOpenPrice(),
                                                             newSL,
                                                             tp,
                                                             buycolor
                                                             );
                                else if (  ModBuy == false )
                                     {     Print( "OrderModify failed with error #",
                                                   GetLastError()
                                                   );
                                     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

### For the moment being,
refine the code
and
add self-debuging / tracing code

After **`OrderModify()`** use a self-debugging / journaling `Print( StringFormat( ... ) )` to document all instructed values used in the actual `OrderModify()` call and also the remote-execution ( { server-side | StrategyTester } ) reported issues.

The current code does not enter into such self-diagnostics and **`ModSell`** is not inspected at all, **`ModBuy`** is inspected only at uncertain conditions / by-coincidence at some future visit of the `for(){...}` code-execution path to a part after **`newSL == sl`** ( and all above stated conditions are just by chance met too )

---

### Next, check an assigned value of `tp`

As stated above,

```
/*Local  Declarations*/
...
tp                   =  OrderTakeProfit();
```

which introduces **a reasonable doubt**, that **re-using** of this ( **inherently uncertain value**, as no one knows, which **`OrderSelect()`** was the last one that set a **`db.Pool`** pointer to decide, from which record from the `db.Pool` this very`OrderTakeProfit()` would accidentally read ( if any record is present in `db.Pool` already ) **inside the whole `for(){...}` traversing** the `db.Pool` records **will not meet conditions for setting properly a TakeProfit price in the next series of `OrderModify()` calls.**

This seems to be the root cause, or a source of unhandled exceptions to the valid, Broker-compliant, `OrderModify()` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (newSL != sl ) {
    ModSell = OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                           OrderOpenPrice(),
                           OrderOpenPrice(),
                           0,
                           OrderExpiration(),
                           clrRed
                          );
    if(ModBuy == false )
        Print( "OrderModify failed with error #", GetLastError());
}
```

Then check the Expert-tab for error-message if it fails to set the stop.

Also, you need to take note that StopLoss will ONLY occur if you are on the right chart-timeframe; Otherwise, it won't even get into the if-statements.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I actually paid a freelancer to do it in the end as I was getting bored with trying yo work it out, only to find that I had it in "Open Prices Only" mode, yikes! This meant that the initial code I put up here was absolutely fine! :-)